# jQuery code not firing

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery pop-up dialog, and at the top there is a **close** link. For some reason the code is never called here: I've watched in the debugger.

I assume it is something simple, as the open code works fine.

The javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dialogOpen').click(function() {
    console.log("link clicked");
    openDialog('#dialog');
  });

$('#dialog').find('.ok')
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("ok clicked");
    closeDialog(this);
  })
});

function openDialog(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .clone()
    .appendTo('#overlay')
    .show()
    .parent()
    .fadeIn('fast');
  }

function closeDialog(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .parents('#overlay')
    .fadeOut('fast', function() {
       $(this)
         .find('.dialog')
         .remove();
       });
}
```

The html snippet:

```
  <div id="dialog" class="dialog">
     <a href="#" class="ok">Close Dialog</a>
  <div>
```

The full code is here: https://gist.github.com/sfcarroll/4739040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try :

```
$('body').on('click', '.dialog .ok', function() {
    console.log("ok clicked");
    closeDialog(this);
  })
});
```

Comment: An alternative is to copy events in the clone method: .clone(true)

Comment: That's interesting epignosisx, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone else is applying the event on the selector instead of the object I thought I'd go about it differently.

The problem is that you add the event to the original html, but when you `clone` the html you don't copy the event's with it. add a `true` as argument and you should be set:

```
function openDialog(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .clone(true)
    .appendTo('#overlay')
    .show()
    .parent()
    .fadeIn('fast');
  }
```

see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: I've tested it out and the .clone(true) option works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
$('#dialog').find('.ok')
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("ok clicked");
    closeDialog(this);
  })
});
```

bind event to **existing html nodes**. It is called before your new `#dialog` are created, thus these new `#dialog` doesn't have a callback called on the click on their `.ok`. The reason is that `.clone` doesn't clone the event  bound on the cloned element.

Use a delegate handle, like this :

```
$(document).on('#dialog .ok', 'click', function () {
  // Your click handler here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your .on on the button itsself. It should be on a parent so it can catch the click it as it bubbles up. Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dialog .ok', function() {
    console.log("ok clicked");
    closeDialog(this);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your openDialog function you are cloning the dialog and thus creating a new instance of it. <del>You would either have to bind to the click event afterwards or use `$('#dialog .ok').live('click', data, handler);` to have it bound to new DOM elements.</del>

Comment: live is deprecated as of 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9. He is going the right way with .on

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dialogOpen').click(function() {
    console.log("link clicked");
    openDialog('#dialog');
  });


});

function openDialog(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .clone()
    .appendTo('#overlay')
    .show()
    .parent()
    .fadeIn('fast');

    $('#dialog').find('.ok')
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log("ok clicked");
    closeDialog(this);
  });

}

function closeDialog(selector) {
  $(selector)
  .parents('#overlay')
  .fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this)
      .find('.dialog')
      .remove();
  });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J9fWg/)**

Intially you had applied .dialog class to #dialog div, which contains `display:none` CSS , so intially DOM will not have that div on which you can bind event, so it was not firing.

Comment: I think my answer was not updated well when you had watched... check my updated answer